# Partial query failure: Low memory condition - Kusto

Tags: syntax-error, azure-data-explorer

I am new to Kusto, and recently I have been facing this error:

```
Partial query failure: Low memory condition (E_LOW_MEMORY_CONDITION). (message: 'bad allocation', details: '')
```

It disappears when I change the JOIN from Out to inner.

What does it mean and how can I can fix it?

It also appeared when I connected PowerBI to Kusto trying to filter on table by other.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atgRP.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have:

1. Query using 'join'
2. When run - it results with low-memory condition

Given this two facts are true - I would recommend you looking on how to make your join distributed using technique called "query data-shuffling" and described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/shufflequery

(spoiler: you can use hint.shufllekey= in your query to hint join/summarize operators how to shuffle the data across nodes)

Comment: I used `hint.shufflekey = [ColumnName]` then it threw a different error about the result set being too large but it returned results. Then I added limit 100 and my query ran with no errors.

Comment: Next to that, I also limited the amount of results returned with `take`. Make sure you run `join` before `take`, it performs better.